# Is DeflateAlterETag supported in Apache 2.4.x

Tags: apache-2.4

Apache's [documentation for mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_deflate.html#deflatealteretag) appears to state that `DeflateAlterETag` is supported from Apache version 2.4.42.

Our Apache webserver (compiled on Solaris by our corporate IT as of 2020-09-23) reports it is version 2.4.46, but it throws a syntax error `Invalid command 'DeflateAlterETag'`. `mod_deflate` is definitely enabled.

Is this just a documentation error, or should the command be available?